# How to initialize the std::optional of a user defined data type

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to learn new features of C++ 17.

Please find the below code:

```
class Test
{
public:
      Test(int x):y(x){}
      ~Test(){}
      int getx()
      {
          return x;
      }
private:
      int x;
};
struct Container
{
    std::optional<Test> test;
};
int main()
{
    struct Container obj;
    // here i want to initialize the member "test" of 
    // struct Container
    obj.test = make_optional<Test>(10); ----> is this correct??
}
```

Can someone please let me know how to initialize a `std::optional`? For example, if I declare it like:

```
std::optional<Test> t
```

How can I initialize it?

Comment: `std::optional` will be in C++17.

Comment: @Zereges Yes its in C++17. But i want to know how can i initialize it after declaration.

Comment: Do note you initialize when you declare it.  After you declare it you can only assign to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you very much for your comment. Yes as you can see i have declared it inside the structure. So when i create the object of the structure it will be intialized automatically and hold any thing as per the property of std::optional. As correctly pointed out by you i want to assign it to a valid Test object. Can you please let me know how can i do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
obj.test = make_optional<Test>(10);
```

> ----> is this correct??

Yes it is. You could also do it like this:

```
obj.test = Test(10);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and reply.

Comment: You can also use it like this: `obj.test = 10;` thanks to implicit conversion.
Could you please accept this answer.

Comment: Another possibility is `obj.test = {10};` which allows you to specify multiple arguments in case the constructor has multiple parameters.